# Voodoo via particle entanglement

Tags: physics, science-in-society

In a world where science has advanced to the point of a healthy understanding of particle physics, scientists have begun working towards remote matter manipulation. In theory, it seems that one would be able to entangle particles of a person in order to gain some control over that particle.

**Could particle entanglement be used to create a voodoo doll, or something similar, that could then be used to leverage said person by influencing the atoms in their body?**

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986): The problem cannot be fixed if the OP is not made aware of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There is a lot of nonsense out there about the nature of quantum-entangled particles. They don't work like "You move one, and the other moves too." Rather, the reality of it is much more disappointing. Long story short, to avoid going too deep into quantum mechanics, when the state of one of the particles is observed, the other particle immediately enters the opposite state. This effect is a one-time thing, and has nothing to do with physical motion of the particles.

**TL;DR:** No, you could not, because quantum entanglement doesn't work that way.

Source: Me, as an aspiring theoretical physicist. Feel free to check out the first couple paragraphs of the Wikipedia page, it basically says the same thing, but with more jargon.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement

Comment: Hello, *SuperKael*, and welcome to Worldbuilding!  Please take our [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the way the site works.  Have a nice day!

Comment: I like how your negative starts with *unfortunately*.